# sum by row accros columns and conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum

I have a dataframe with ninety columns (in the example only 6) and multiple rows. I would like to sum by rows on all the columns but only when the value is 4 or 5. In the results I would like the number of time the conditions is realised. I don't know how to add this condition in the following code.

I take any help, thank you.

```
df = data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,5,5,2,2,5,5,4,4,4,2,2,5), 
                B = c(2,2,2,5,5,4,2,3,1,4,1,4,5,2,5), 
                C = c(5,3,3,5,5,2,1,5,5,1,1,4,1,2,5), 
                D = c(4,5,5,3,5,5,1,5,5,4,2,3,2,2,1),
                E = c(1,2,2,2,5,2,5,3,3,4,4,4,2,2,1),
                H = c(1,2,2,3,5,2,2,5,3,1,4,4,4,2,3))

> df
   A B C D E H
1  1 2 5 4 1 1
2  2 2 3 5 2 2
3  2 2 3 5 2 2
4  5 5 5 3 2 3
5  5 5 5 5 5 5
6  2 4 2 5 2 2
7  2 2 1 1 5 2
8  5 3 5 5 3 5
9  5 1 5 5 3 3
10 4 4 1 4 4 1
11 4 1 1 2 4 4
12 4 4 4 3 4 4
13 2 5 1 2 2 4
14 2 2 2 2 2 2
15 5 5 5 1 1 3
```

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```r
df$sum_4_5 <- apply(df, 1, \(x) sum(x[x %in% 4:5]))
```

Its `dplyr` equivalent:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum_4_5 = c_across(everything()) %>% { sum(.[. %in% 4:5]) }) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 15 × 7
#        A     B     C     D     E     H sum_4_5
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1     1     2     5     4     1     1       9
#  2     2     2     3     5     2     2       5
#  3     2     2     3     5     2     2       5
#  4     5     5     5     3     2     3      15
#  5     5     5     5     5     5     5      30
# ...
```

---

##### Update

If you want to get the number of 4 and 5 in each row, the code will be easier:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(sum_4_5 = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x %in% 4:5)))

# # A tibble: 15 × 7
#        A     B     C     D     E     H sum_4_5
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1     1     2     5     4     1     1       2
#  2     2     2     3     5     2     2       1
#  3     2     2     3     5     2     2       1
#  4     5     5     5     3     2     3       3
#  5     5     5     5     5     5     5       6
# ...
```

Comment: I've always found nested `%>%` to be confusing; if you define `sumif <- function(x, val) sum(x[x %in% val])`, then you can reduce the mutate to `sumif(c_across(everything()), 4:5)`

Comment: I am sorry, I was not clear enough. I would like to sum the number of time the conditions is realised. For example, on line 1 I expect 2, on line 2 I expect 1...

Comment: Use `mutate(sum = sum(c_across(where(is.numeric)) %in% 4:5)) %>%` then

Comment: @PatrickParts see my update! r2evans, Maël Thanks all of you for informative suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, Sum4o5 := rowSums(.SD == 4 | .SD == 5)]

df
    A B C D E H Sum4o5
 1: 1 2 5 4 1 1      2
 2: 2 2 3 5 2 2      1
 3: 2 2 3 5 2 2      1
 4: 5 5 5 3 2 3      3
 5: 5 5 5 5 5 5      6
 6: 2 4 2 5 2 2      2
 7: 2 2 1 1 5 2      1
 8: 5 3 5 5 3 5      4
 9: 5 1 5 5 3 3      3
10: 4 4 1 4 4 1      4
11: 4 1 1 2 4 4      3
12: 4 4 4 3 4 4      5
13: 2 5 1 2 2 4      2
14: 2 2 2 2 2 2      0
15: 5 5 5 1 1 3      3
```